# Resolve Adal Token for Http Interceptor

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, adal.js

I am trying to write an angular (4) interceptor which adds the authorization token;

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private _adal: AdalService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):  Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const resource = this._adal.GetResourceForEndpoint(req.url);

    var token;

    this._adal.acquireToken(resource)
      .subscribe(function (token) {
        token = token;
      });

    const authReq = req.clone({setHeaders: {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`}});

    return next.handle(authReq);   
  }
}
```

Straight away I knew this was wrong, `token` is being set in an asynchronous fashion and therefore when the headers are being set, `token` is undefined.

My problem is, how do I make this work? `acquireToken` is from the Adal npm package which return `Observable<string>`. The interceptor is part of Angular's framework and expects `Observable<HttpEvent<any>>` to be returned.

Is there any way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

#### FYI

I was previously using `getCachedToken` which just returns a string. This was working great until we started using multiple end points. It seems Adal does not cache tokens for ALL end points.

I am using the following Adal [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-adal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try returning observable after response has come:

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private _adal: AdalService) {}
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):  Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
     return this._adal.acquireToken(this._adal.GetResourceForEndpoint(req.url))
        .switchMap(function (token) {
             return next.handle(req.clone({setHeaders: {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`}})); 
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution seems to cause the following error: `Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error`. It is making the Http request albeit without the authorization header. I have logged the token within the `switchMap` and it is being generated? I'm finding it hard to tell if this error I am getting is being caused by the interceptor or not.

Comment: It turns out, it helps if the API is running. *facepalm*. Is there any chance you could just give a one line explanation of the `switchMap` magic?

Comment: @Heberda `switchMap` looks the same as `map`. But `map` tells that you return `Observable` of the same type and `switchMap` tells that it changes type. For example: `intercept` method should return `Observable<HttpEvent<any>>` but your `this._adal.acquireToken` method returns `Observable<string>` and if you use `map` it will cause an error as map should also return `Observable<string>` in your case but it returns `Observable<HttpEvent<any>>`. That's the case

Comment: Thanks, I find this anything but intuitive! Still I have a nice clean solution, thank you.